# multiple select dropdown with avatar React Native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I want to have a multi select dropdown with avatar just like this library https://github.com/logisticinfotech/react-native-contact-multi-select but this library only works for contacts and I want to have the same dropdown style and chips but for data stored in an array. Any solutions please ?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Eldjotnar/react-native-autocomplete-tags
give it a try may be you would get what you want to do.
its searchable and under the wood they use flatlist which can be customized